# WARNING:tensorflow - initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated

Tags: python, tensorflow

While initializaing tensorflow

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

get below warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:/Projects/Python/DLPractice/boston_housing.py:75 in <module>.: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
```

How to remove the warning and use updated code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution is to use the updated method `global_variables_initializer()` instead of `initialize_all_variables`

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Comment: FYI, this change is not back compatible with versions of TensorFlow prior to r1.0 (e.g. on r0.11 it will fail with an `AttributeError`).  Today the deprecated code still works on TensorFlow r1.3, so I recommend making this change with caution. :-)